# How to make the browser remember what the user choose?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code. I don't really know anything about Javascript so I pretty much found it on the internet. What it does basically is closes the big header image at the top of the page. I want to know how do I make it so that the browser remembers what the user has chosen? FOr example if the person clicks to hide it and then you reload the page, it should remain hidden and not default to the original.

```
<script language='javascript'>
function toggle() {
var pagehead = document.getElementById(&quot;HTML6&quot;);
var xbutton = document.getElementById(&quot;hide-header&quot;);
if(pagehead.style.display == &quot;none&quot;) {
pagehead.style.display = &quot;block&quot;;
xbutton.innerHTML = &quot;<img border='0' src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-S5r38GtSF6s/Ui04r4eS0yI/AAAAAAAADpQ/qRnrSX2MpcY/w16-h15-no/close+X.png'/>&quot;;
}
else {
pagehead.style.display = &quot;none&quot;;
xbutton.innerHTML = &quot;<img border='0' src='https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-S5r38GtSF6s/Ui04r4eS0yI/AAAAAAAADpQ/qRnrSX2MpcY/w16-h15-no/close+X.png'/>&quot;;
}
} 
</script>
```

Not sure if it's even possible. I have no idea really.
Here is my website for reference: [linkvier.com](http://www.linkvier.com/)
I really hope I can get this code to work since I plan on using it on ads and stuff as well.

Comment: as far as i know http is stateless you can yse cookies

Comment: You can use browser cookies or localstorage .. refer http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp for more info on localstorage

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the browser cookies. Take a look at [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). There are examples there.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know http is stateless you can use cookies  to get this 
**Read** [Stateless_protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)

look at checkCookie() getCookie(c_name) and  setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) here @
[w3schools Cookie Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to support old browsers then check out html's 5 [localStorage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LocalStorage#localStorage) it's pretty awesome. :-)

For older browsers use cookies or one of those [scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage#localStorage) that emulate localStorage using cookies.